# Add total number of reviews under IMPACT box

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

At the right side in Activity page of user, there is box heading "IMPACT" which shows:

- Number of people reached
- Number of helpful flags
- Number of vote cast

[image: screen-shot]

As well as helpful flags, I think reviewing is **contribution for improving the site and moderation**.

> Review queues (also known as review tasks) contain posts that possibly
>   need community attention, as determined by the system or other
>   community users

***Reviews show the contribution for finding + fixing stuff.***

So, feature-request to add one thing:

- Number of reviews

And link it to [all actions > reviews](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=reviews) (?tab=activity&sort=reviews)

Comment: But I'd also add number of *helpful* reviews, since reviews alone don't really say anything about meaningful and constructive contribution.

Comment: @ChristianRau I'd base it on whatever the badges base it on to be honest.

Comment: @ChristianRau, what constitutes a "helpful" review?  Is closing a wildly off-topic question helpful?  How about deleting low-quality spam?  What about a reopen vote that ages away?

Comment: @Mark A suggested edit that gets accepted, a delete-vote that gets deleted, a close-cote that gets closed and a reopen-vote that gets reopened would be a start. Does it cover all the boundary cases? Maybe not, but it is a start, and would provide a counter weight to the millions of wrongly accepted edits from incorrect reviewers.

Comment: I requested this in the feedback topic; it was status-declined because the box doesn't have space for another number. (Sorry, can't paste in a link from my phone.)